# Why is the middle of this sweet potato dark?

Tags: vegetables, mold, sweet-potatoes

This is a red-skinned white-fleshed sweet potato.  I don't know what kind.  I have never tried one before, I have only had the orange kind.

The outside looked OK.  There were no black spots or damaged areas.  The inside had this darkness all through the middle.  It was not soft or pithy and did not smell bad.

What is it?  Mold?  Fusarium?

[image: suspicious sweet potato]

Comment: Probably just random discoloration.  If the texture and smell is the same as the rest of the potato, then I'd just use it.